# How to access Google Glass contact photos when creating new timeline cards?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am building GlassWare that will add a timeline card to indicate one of a user's friends has performed some action. On the card, I would like to show an image of the friend.

If the Glass user has already added that friend as a Glass Contact, then the device may already have the friend's image. I have the friend's email and am trying to get at that image like so:

1. Call Contacts/List to get the contacts
2. Cycle through that list looking for one with a matching email address
3. Grab the imageUrl from the contact and use it in the html for my new timeline card

I'm facing 2 problems with this approach:

1. The Contacts/List is coming back empty.
2. The Contact class doesn't appear to have an email property

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible through Glass. The Contacts that you see are only those that your Glassware has created - your Glassware does not have access to the contacts created by other Glassware. This makes sense from a privacy perspective - a Glass Owner does not necessarily want you to have unrestricted access to who their contacts may be.

You may wish to look into using the [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/), which can give you access to those people that a user has specifically given you access to. When the user approves your Glassware, they also approve which people your app can find out about. From here, you can use some of that user's information, including their profile picture.

Comment: Hmm... on Android it is a matter of requesting the READ_CONTACTS permission. That there is no equivalent for Glass seems rather limiting.